# Expressjs Routes are invoked twice when running server and browsing using browser

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Expressjs Routes are invoked twice when running

OS System Environment: Windows 11, ExpressJS ("express": "^4.18.1", "version": "4.18.1"), Node v16.15.0

```
const url = require('url');
const path = require("path");
const express = require('express');

let app = express();
console.log("instantiation");

app.use("/language", function (req, res) {
    const queryObject = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    console.log("/ language");
    res.send("Testing server : language");
});

app.use("/", function (req, res) {
    console.log("/ path");
    res.send("Testing server : main page");
});

app.use("*", function (req, res) {
    console.log("* path");
    res.send(`"Testing my server"`);
});

app.listen(3001, "127.0.0.1", function () {
    console.log(`Server listening at ` + 3001);
});
```

Update (The following `/` route is still invoked twice). Anything I am missing?:

```
const url = require('url');
const path = require("path");
const express = require('express');

let app = express();
console.log("instantiation");

app.use("/language", function (req, res) {
    const queryObject = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    console.log("/ language");
    res.send("Testing server : language");
});

app.use("/", function (req, res) {
    console.log("/ path");
    res.send("Testing server : main page");
});

app.listen(3001, "127.0.0.1", function () {
    console.log(`Server listening at ` + 3001);
});
```

Is it my system or a real problem with express/node?

Comment: You can safely assume it's not a problem with Express/Node. If you mean the `* path` message is being logged multiple times, that is to be expected because it's basically a catch-all route handler.

Comment: Ok. Ouch. Missed it. I presumed this * route is supposed to handle only when no other routes above mentioned are available. That is what I remembered using. Is there an option that * is invoked only when other routes are not there? Or do I have to use a route not available error handler or is `/` enough

Comment: You're correct in saying that the `*` route will only be used if there aren't any other matching handlers, but do consider that browsers may request more than just the URL you navigate to (for instance, `/favicon.ico`)

Comment: @robertklep unfotunately now I am not using any routes other than `/language` and `/` and even then the `/` route is invoked twice. Is this something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your route handler is invoked multiple times is because you're using `app.use('/')` instead of specific method handlers like `app.get('/')` or `app.post('/')`.

`app.use()` is meant for adding middleware, and will match the *base* of a requested path (as opposed to using the method handlers, which will match the *full* path).

In other words `app.use('/')` will match *any* request that isn't already handled by other handlers declared before it. This includes requests to `/favicon.ico`, which a browser usually performs when opening a page. It will also match requests to `/foo/bar`, for instance.

More info on `app.use()` can be found [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use).

Comment: Thank you. This was messy and you resolved it. I owe you a coffee. Bad me (day)